# how can I add lazy loading to this list?

Tags: flutter

This is the how I fetch the posts in postList from firebase firestore,  I need a function that works to get more posts on scroll. This next set of posts have to  start after the last post that is displayed in this initial list and add to this list as the user scrolls as long as there are posts in the firestore.

```
class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
  List<Post> _posts = [];
   ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setupFeed();
     _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

_scrollListener() {
    setState(() {
      if (_controller.position.atEdge) {
        if (_controller.position.pixels == 0) {


        } else {
          _getMore();

        }
      }
    });
  }
  _setupFeed() async {
    List<Post> posts = await DatabaseService.getFeedPosts(widget.currentUserId);
    setState(() {
      _posts = posts;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          'New List',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 35.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => _setupFeed(),
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: _controller,
          itemCount: _posts.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            Post post = _posts[index];
            return FutureBuilder(
              future: DatabaseService.getUserWithId(post.authorId),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return SizedBox.shrink();
                }
                User author = snapshot.data;
                return PostView(
                  currentUserId: widget.currentUserId,
                  post: post,
                  author: author,
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is how i fetch the list of posts

```
static Future<List<Post>> getFeedPosts(String userId) async {
    QuerySnapshot feedSnapshot = await feedsRef
        .document(userId)
        .collection('userFeed')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        .limit(30)
        .getDocuments();
    List<Post> posts =
        feedSnapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDoc(doc)).toList();
    return posts;
  }
```

Comment: What is the current behavior ? No post are added ? Or the list of posts change totally ?

Comment: I set the limit to 30 so 30 posts are loaded in the postList but how do i load more on scroll? Because if i don't set the limit then it loads all the posts that are there in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

I think doing this will solve your issue:

You have to edit your getFeedPosts to collect your posts starting at a given index:

*I'm not familiar to FireStore, I've found the `startAt()` method on docs*

**EDIT: I've misunderstood a Firestore concept, so I've change `startAt()` to `startAfter()` following Francisco Javier Snchez advice**

```dart
static Future<List<Post>> getFeedPosts(String userId, TimeStamp start) async {
  QuerySnapshot feedSnapshot = await feedsRef
      .document(userId)
      .collection('userFeed')
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .startAfter(start)
      .limit(30)
      .getDocuments();
  List<Post> posts =
      feedSnapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDoc(doc)).toList();
  return posts;
}
```

Now you can query it like this:

```dart
_getMore() async {
  // You have to give the timestamp of the last post here
  // Change this line by the right way...
  List<Post> posts = await DatabaseService.getFeedPosts(widget.currentUserId, _posts[_posts.length - 1].timestamp);
  setState(() {
    // Do += instead of =, += will add fetched posts to the current list, = will overwrite the whole list
    _posts += posts;
  });
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: But how would this fetch the posts starting after the last post in the initially loaded list?

Comment: @notabot It will use the current loaded list length, (which is initially 30) to fetch the 30 next posts, after 30 posts. When you will scroll to the end a second time, the number of loaded posts will be 60, so calling this method will fetch the 30 next posts, after 60 posts, and so on...

Comment: @na2axl just to let you know, startAt and startAfter refer to the field that you use in orderBy. If you try to feed a startIndex to a timestamp, it will fail.

Comment: @FranciscoJavierSnchez sorry I've misunderstood this concept, I've updated my answer

Comment: but how do i mention the startAfter(timestamp of the last fecthed document here)?

Comment: In your `Post` class there is no `timestamp` field ? If yes, just doing `_posts[_posts.length - 1].timestamp` can be enough, since fetched data are already sorted by timestamp

Comment: yes i have a timestamp field which is for the sole purpose of sorting the posts.

Comment: @notabot so you can use this field, by calling `DatabaseService.getFeedPosts(widget.currentUserId, _posts[_posts.length - 1].timestamp);`. Your list of posts is already sorted, so getting the last post with `_posts[_posts.length - 1]` will return the **last fetched post ordered by timestamp**, so you can this post `timestamp` in the `startAfter()` method

Answer (score 2):

na2axl answer was *almost* right. I will add here an explanation and example of how to use `startAfter()`

If you check the [documentation on pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query), you will see that you need to use `startAfter()` referencing whatever filter you used. In your case you are ordering using `timestamp` so your next query should look like this:

```
static Future<List<Post>> getNextFeedPosts(String userId, TimeStamp timestamp) async {
    QuerySnapshot feedSnapshot = await feedsRef
        .document(userId)
        .collection('userFeed')
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
        //Here you need to let Firebase know which is the last document you fetched
        //using its timesTamp
        .startAfter(timestamp)
        .limit(30)
        .getDocuments();
    List<Post> posts =
        feedSnapshot.documents.map((doc) => Post.fromDoc(doc)).toList();
    return posts;
  }
```

This means that your next query will still be ordered by a `timestamp` but the first document retrieved will be **after** the `timestamp` on `startAfter`

I hope this helps, however, you can check the documentation as there are other examples!

Comment: how do i mention the timestamp of the last document because it is not possible to know the exact timestamp or how do i do it?? I'm sorry if this sounds lame  I'm just a beginner here.:)

Comment: As you are ordering the documents by 'timestamp', it means that it is already stored in your database. If you check the last document retreived from Firebase, it will have a timestamp, which you can use with startAfter in your next query to download the next 30 results.

Comment: I read the documentation and tried to mention the timestamp accordingly at first but it gave some error in the console, it'd be nice if you could show how to mention the last doc in this case.

Comment: QueryDocumentSnapshot lastDoc = docs.get(docs.size() - 1);                             
   'Query secondPage = cities.orderBy("population").startAfter(lastDoc).limit(25);'                                this is how it shows in the documentation

Comment: Does your Post objet has a DateTime?

Comment: the class "Post" . has  a timstamp field it updates  the DateTime of the post created .

Comment: Use the timestamp from your last fetched post and use it in the startAfter method. Like this: getNextFeedPosts(widget.currentUserId, posts.last.timestamp). Something like that might work.